# What kind of SQL join is this?

Tags: sql, join, union

Say for some reason I have employees in two separate tables, employee1 and employee2

I just want to add them together, as if they are stacked on top of each other.

something like:

```
select all from employee1 and employee2 where name = bubba
```

i know im generalizing, this will be in postgres eventually so if there are any specifics there i should watch for thanks

Comment: fastest gun in the west - observe.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SELECT field1, field2, field2 FROM tableA WHERE field1='x'
UNION
SELECT field1, field2, field2 FROM tableB WHERE field1='x'
```

Use `UNION ALL` if you want every record, even repeats.

Comment: +1 for writing out column names, this is important as the columns may not exist in the same order in each table, and bonus credit for explaining use of UNION ALL.

Comment: +1 about column names too.  Its to generic and open for failure if just an "*" from a table.  Especially if different column names, sizes, sequences, etc will cause the UNION to crash.  Better to be explicit about what is desired than generic and fail

Answer (score 4):

You'll just want to do a union

```
select * from Employee1 where name = 'bubba'
union
select * from Employee2 where name = 'bubba'
```

Comment: if you truely want the results stacked, you should use UNION ALL, UNION will remove the dupes, UNION ALL with include them
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/interactive/queries-union.html

Answer (score 3):

You will want to use the [UNION](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.1/static/typeconv-union-case.html) keyword

```
select * from employee1 where name = 'bubba'
union
select * from employee2 where name = 'bubba'
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  Was it edited? As it is, it's correct.

Comment: No edits, my guess is someone with an answer is down voting other answers so theirs appear on top.

Comment: I'll upvote you, since I hate when people downvote correct answers

Comment: You should never use select * in a union statement. Always explicitly state the column names. Other wise things will break if one table is changed t and the other is not or even worse if some idiot decides to rearrange the column order on a table.

Comment: UNION ALL should be used as dupes are wanted

Answer (score 2):

In most databases what you are requesting is called a [UNION](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.1/static/queries-union.html) and written like this:

```
select all from employee1 where name = bubba

UNION

select all from employee2 where name = bubba
```

This comes from [Relational Algebra's "union" operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_union), one of its primitives.

Please note that UNION follows set unions, namely, it will, for any rows which are duplicate between E1 and E2 tables, only select ONE copy of the row. If you wish to select all copies, use "UNION ALL" operator.

Answer (score 1):

I think you refer to the [UNION](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.1/static/typeconv-union-case.html) operation.

Answer (score 1):

If the table have the same schema then

```
SELECT * FROM employee1 UNION SELECT * FROM employee2
```

Both tables must have the same number of columns and the columns must be of a similar type.

Answer (score 1):

Its a union I guess

Select * from employee 1 where name = 'bubba'

union

select * from employee2 where name = 'bubba'

Use union all if you want duplicates as well.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a "union all":

```
select * from employee1
union all
select * from employee2;
```

Column types and order must match, or you'll need to provide column lists rather than "*" in the select list.  A "where" clause can be added to either or both "select" statements.

Without "all", any duplicate rows between the two queries will be collapsed into a single row.  If that's what you want instead, just remove "all".

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you want `UNION`. However if you truely want the results stacked, you should use `UNION ALL`. `UNION` will remove the dupes, UNION ALL with include them. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/interactive/queries-union.html

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, union all is quicker to execute as it doesn't have to sort to get rid of duplicates in the two sets.